# Troubleshooting a Tenma 21-10115

Tags: troubleshooting, soldering-iron-station

I recently ran into problems with my Tenma 21-10115 soldering iron.  The temperature was set at 355 C - which I've used regularly for several years know (low but frequent use).  This was the first time I've seen dramatic temperature fluctuations, at which point I power cycled the station.  Now, when I turn on the station, it is clear that the tip is heating up, but the temperature reads 40-60 degrees, bounces to 0, and otherwise is very erratic.  It's as if the thermostat has malfunctioned.

I replaced the tip with no change in behavior.  I removed the tip to inspect the heating element.  I don't know what a "good" heating element is supposed to look like but I don't see any significant signs of charring.  The connections do not seem to be damaged.

Removing the iron from the station, I do get the S-E error indicating that the station does not notice the presence of the tip.

About the only information I've found is this poor review of the iron on Newark's website:

> I really like the 60 watt digital soldering station that uses these, however this part is the weak link of the system. While these heat up very, very quickly and have very long lasting tips - the real issue is that the construction is weak... they loosen, crack and eventually break in the handle area. I also had one where the temperature sensor failed almost immediately, and these were on back-order for the warranty replacement. Frustrating!

Based on that single data point, I may need to simply purchase a new iron. Any suggestions on how to proceed with troubleshooting and if this type of behavior could be expected from a $100 unit that is ~ 2 year old would be appreciated.

Comment: I have been using the US$80 SL30 for 5+ years and have never encountered your temperature instability problem. I am a DIY hobbyist, playing with through hole and SMD components "regularly".

Comment: There are about 4 stages ; driver, heater , sensor and error comparator with threshold ref.  Which part is bad? Power supply?

Comment: I'd be measuring the cable between the iron and base first. Broken or intermittent wires are not unusual. Check the simple stuff first.

Comment: @Kartman I learned that the iron is a HAKKO 907 clone, and when following the troubleshooting options in the HAKKO manual it seems as if the cable is a problem.